# no web.xml in enterprise application project in netbeans

Tags: java, xml, servlets, netbeans, web.xml

I'm using netbeans 7.2.1 with glassfish server 3.1.

I created enterprise application project in netbeans and added JSF framework to the war part of the project. Netbeans didn't create any web.xml and no glassfish-web.xml file, as it creates for web project. Is there special reason for it? As I understand it, the war part of the enterprise application project has same structure as web project...
If web.xml is not needed where the needed configuration should be done, as for example, welcome file ?

If I create web.xml manually, should it syntax be the same as for web application web.xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From servlet 3.0  there is no `web.xml`

There are annotations now to map.

[Annotations Vs. Deployment Descriptor](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html#annotations-vs-deployment-descriptor)

> If I create web.xml manually, should it syntax be the same as for web application web.xml file?

Yes.

[Servlet 3.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: Thanks,  If web.xml is not needed where the needed configuration should be done, as for example, welcome file ?

Comment: Is it possible to still use web.xml instead of annotations? Is it enough to add web.xml add edit it same as before servlet 3.0, or some additional changes should be done for it to take effect?

Comment: @qwerty Yes you can use it.There is no restrictions that you cannot use web.xml.

Comment: where would the annotation go to answer the question of how to configure the welcome file?